# Autenticação Windows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

A minha autenticação do Windows esta se perdendo com o tempo.

Faço a seguinte validação:

```
if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
    dsHostName = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1].ToString();
```

-Authentication IIS
Anonimo: Desabilitado
Windows: Habilitado

No primeiro acesso faz a autenticação, quero força a autenticação quando se perder, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]